# Как в js или jquery удалить часть строки между двумя символами /word/

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строка (url адрес) "/glavnaya/promotions/..."

нужно удалить /glavnaya/ - только первое слово, оно может меняться динамически, чтобы строка имела вид "promotions/..."

Не знаю как это сделать через .replace()

За помощь буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если только англ. буквы, то так

```
var str = '/glavnaya/promotions/...';
var newStr = str.replace(/(\/[a-z]+\/)/, '');
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: Я написал такое же регулярное выражение, но удалилось вообще всё, тк у каждого слова с двух стон стоят знаки "/". Нужно удалить только /первое слово/

Comment: `/(\/[a-z]+\/)/` - в таком варианте удаляет только первое `/word/`

Comment: И вправду. Всё заработало. Спасибо большое!